# grep -f r t, how to make the result sort by r, not t

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, grep

```
$ cat r
1
2
$ cat t
22
11
$ grep -f r t
22
11
```

The result is provided according to the sequence in `t`, how can I get the result sorted by `r`?

Comment: @fedorqui this is just a simple example, actually, in my case, `r` contains complex regular expressions, so I name it `r`.

Comment: I assume one could always read the pattern file r linewise and do a repeated grep with each line over all of t. That would trivially sort the result by pattern: `cat r|while read pattern ; do grep "$pattern" t; done`. The example may not be completely general with respect to proper pattern quoting though.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a script which keeps everything in memory, or you could apply a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).  Here is a brief attempt at doing the latter.

Change your `r` file into a `sed` script which prints an index number for each match:

```
/1/s/^/00001 /
/2/s/^/00002 /
```

Use `sed` instead of `grep`, and sort by the prefix; then discard the prefix.

```
sed -f r t | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f2- >output
```

Creating the `sed` script should not be too hard; here is a simple Awk script (oh, the irony!)

```
awk '{ printf("/%s/s/^/%05i /\n", $0, NR) }' r >r.sed
```

If you have slashes in your regexes, things will have to be slightly more complicated.  Remember that `/foo/` can also be written `\:foo:` so if you can find a suitable delimiter which does not occur in your data, that's probably the easiest workaround.

If your `sed` can read a script from standard input (not all of them can, but Linux `sed` should be fine) you can avoid using a temporary file; the entire pipeline is then

```
awk '{ printf("/%s/s/^/%05i /\n", $0, NR) }' r |
sed -f - t | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f2- >output
```